# GNU parallel doesn't seem to reread sshloginfile while running

Tags: gnu-parallel

Am trying get parallel to dynamically add/remove processing nodes, and I'm able to specify which hosts to run on using --sshloginfile.

Unfortunately changing the entries in sshloginfile while parallel is running doesn't seem to change which hosts are used (i.e. sshloginfile doesn't seem to be re-read during execution).

Am running version 20130922 on Ubuntu 14.04, could this be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see the same issue with 20161222?

Comment: Unfortunately no backport for parallel, installed 20161222 from source and it works now, many thanks! :)